# SIPS image resize for batch size and namming

Tags: macos, terminal, grep, sips

I would like a quick/simple way to use SIPS to resize images to the sizes I want.

Currently- I have to do each file one-by-one, including runnings the sips command, then renaming the file and copying it to another directory.

Ideally- I could automate this to work like the following.

In terminal:

`sips -Z 500 *.png`

rename the *FILENAME*_500x.png

`sips -Z 1000 *.png`

rename the *FILENAME*_1000x.png

`sips -Z 1500 *.png`

rename the *FILENAME*_1000x.png

Answer (score 1):

Define this function in your shell:

```
function resize() {for f in *.png; do sips -Z "$1" "$f"; mv "$f" "${f/.png/_$1x.png}"; done }
```

Then change current directory to where you want to resize images:

```
cd YourFolderContainsPNGFiles
```

Finally invoke resize function like this:

```
resize 500
```

For different `pixelsWH` change the argument:

```
resize 1500
```

The function resizes all `*.png` files in the current folder with the given argument and then appends `_pixelWH` to the file name.